# bgcolor on td or tr table element - html email

Tags: html, colors, background, html-table

I want to minimise bloat on my html email inline styles but retain as much client support as possible, wondering which which is it better to apply bgcolor too.

EACH `<td>` but there's a lot of bloat

```
<tr>
  <td bgcolor="#000000"></td>
  <td bgcolor="#000000"></td>
</tr>
```

or

PARENT `<tr>` which minimises but it is supported?

```
<tr bgcolor="#00000">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

From short testing all sibling `<td>`'s inherit the colour but wondering what support this has. The following [article](https://litmus.com/blog/background-colors-html-email) mentions about background colours but doesn't mention anything about the `<tr>` element.

Comment: why not just use css to remove all bloat from your html? this one line colors all your rows: `table > tr { background-color:black;}`

Comment: @Banana - building a html email and not all email client support css. best to inline styles

Answer (score 0):

tr will apply background color to each td element 
It is highly supported.  Normally tr is used for determining odd or even background color as well.

```
<tr class="${(c % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">


The <tr> tag defines a row in an HTML table. 

A <tr> element contains one or more <th> or <td> elements. color can
be applied to the row using bgcolor. bgcolor    rgb(x,x,x) #xxxxxx
colorname   Not supported in HTML5. Specifies a background color for a
table row
```